# Chrome loading stylesheet from disk cache, never memory cache

Tags: google-chrome, caching

I'm trying to figure out why a stylesheet from a website I'm developing always loads via Chrome's disk cache instead of Chrome's memory cache. Expires dates are set for the file. All other resources are loaded from the memory cache.

[image: Network screenshot from Chrome]

Comment: Interesting, so instead of using the min.css file I used the regular .css file and it loads in 2ms from the disk cache now.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to force Chrome to load CSS from memory cache? This has becoming a bottleneck for the pages I'm working on since it takes as long to load from disk cache as to load it again from CDN.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Load files manually into a ramdisk**:

- Windows: [ImDisk Toolkit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/imdisk-toolkit/) (Tip: check the "dynamic allocation" to save on ram space, prefer to use ExFat instead of NTFS if you'd like to save on a few megabytes upon creation)

2. I use the node package `npm install http-server -g` to host it locally, since chrome does not allow to load it from `file:///` for security reasons.
3. Load it as usual: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8080/tailwind.min.css">`

Be aware that `http-server` default settings will host the files to the local network alongside just `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

### It might be redundant after the first load, but worth trying

- `http-server` also seems to cache regular disk accesses, as by their [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Caching%20is%20on%20by%20default.%20Add%20%2Dc%2D1%20as%20an%20option%20to%20disable%20caching.).
- On my chrome `96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)` after I refresh the page it appears `(Memory Cache)` for the CSS files I've tried, at the network tab in the element inspector, after I reload the page maybe once, I can't remember.